# How do I get the value of 'name' col, same way I am getting the rows count?

Tags: vb.net

database name is 'randomTable'
first col name is 'id'
2nd col name is 'name'

How do I get the value of 'name' col, same way I am getting the rows count?

Protected Sub BindGridData()

```
' Connect to databse and open database file
Dim da As SqlDataAdapter
Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
Dim query As String = "SELECT * FROM [randomTable]"
Dim sqlConn As New SqlConnection(myCon)

Try
    sqlConn.Open()

    Dim cmd = New SqlCommand(query, myCon)
    da = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim builder As SqlCommandBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(da)
    da.Fill(ds, "randomTable")

    Dim a As Integer = ds.Tables("randomTable").Rows.Count
    If a = 0 Then
        e.Text = "empty"
    End If

    'this line is wrong - ???
    Dim s As String = ds.Tables("randomTable").Columns("name")
    if s = "value1" 
        'do something
    end if

    GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables("randomTable").DefaultView
    GridView1.DataBind()

    sqlConn.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
End Try
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

If you want the rows Count, you can execute a query tu Database "SElect Count() from randomTable". But in specific what do you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

Either index by a specific row or iterate the row collection e.g.

```
Dim s As String = ds.Tables("randomTable").Rows(0).Field(Of String)("name")
If s = "value1" Then
    'do something
End If

' or

For row As Integer = 0 To ds.Tables("randomTable").Rows.Count
    If ds.Tables("randomTable").Rows(row).Field(Of String)("name") = "value1" Then
        ' do something
    End If
Next
```